# Insert into table query fails (MySQL) on task scheduler

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this table:

```
LOT_LOCATION, Zone Attribute, LOTID, DESIGN_ID, QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO, PRIORITY, QA_PROCESS_TYPE, QA_PROCESS_NAME, START_TIME, ENV_TEST_INTERVAL, EST_DURATION_TIME, days, elapsed, END_TIME, CURRENT_QTY, LOCATION, PACKAGE_TYPE, NUMBER_OF_DIE_IN_PKG, LEAD_COUNT, PACKAGE_SIZE, CONFIGURATION_WIDTH, RPM_WW, TC_WEIGHT, QA_BURN_EXPERIMENT, QA_CONTACT_NAME, row_created
'SGBAKE.0006', '', 'CVJKHL2.11', 'NC17P', '110488', '1', 'NPI', 'HI TEMP STORAGE 150C', '2022-07-07 14:02:15', '504', '504', '21', '259', '2022-07-28 14:00:00', '79', 'HI TEMP STORAGE', 'LFBGA', '16', '154/195', '11.5x13.5x1.5', 'X4-X8', '', '0', '', 'SCWEE', '2022-07-18 09:14:48'
'SGBAKE.0006', '', 'CVJNGL2.11', 'B16C', '', '4', 'RPM', 'HI TEMP STORAGE 150C', '2022-07-01 15:07:06', '504', '504', '21', '402', '2022-07-22 15:00:00', '40', 'HI TEMP STORAGE', 'VBGA', '4', '132/187', '12x18x1', 'X4-X8', '202223', '0', '', 'EGBARATHIDAS', '2022-07-18 09:14:48'
'SGBAKE.0006', '', 'CVK9GL2.11', 'J87U', '108976', '1', 'NPI', 'HI TEMP STORAGE 150C', '2022-07-08 09:45:34', '504', '336', '14', '239', '2022-07-22 09:45:00', '80', 'HI TEMP STORAGE', 'VFBGA', '2', '162/200', '9.5x10.5x0.9', '', '', '0', '', 'DSAMMONS', '2022-07-18 09:14:48'
'SGBAKE.0006', '', 'CVKHCL2.11', 'J54K', '', '4', 'RPM', 'HI TEMP STORAGE 150C', '2022-07-08 13:21:08', '1008', '504', '21', '235', '2022-07-29 13:20:00', '40', 'HI TEMP STORAGE', 'LBGA', '2', '100/170', '14x18x1.4', 'X4-X8', '202223', '0', '', 'ZINQUANWONG', '2022-07-18 09:14:48'
'SGBAKE.0006', '', 'CVL9GL2.11', 'J87U', '108976', '1', 'NPI', 'HI TEMP STORAGE 150C', '2022-07-08 09:45:44', '504', '336', '14', '239', '2022-07-22 09:45:00', '79', 'HI TEMP STORAGE', 'VFBGA', '2', '162/200', '9.5x10.5x0.9', '', '', '0', '', 'DSAMMONS', '2022-07-18 09:14:48'
```

I have been facing this issue where the code is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a
CREATE TABLE table_a (LOT_LOCATION VARCHAR(255), 
    LOTID VARCHAR(255), 
    DESIGN_ID VARCHAR(255),
    QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO VARCHAR(255),
    PRIORITY VARCHAR(255),
    QA_PROCESS_TYPE VARCHAR(255), 
    QA_PROCESS_NAME VARCHAR(255), 
    START_TIME DateTime,
    ENV_TEST_INTERVAL VARCHAR(255),
    EST_DURATION_TIME VARCHAR(255),
    days VARCHAR(255),
    elapsed VARCHAR(255),
    END_TIME DateTime,
    CURRENT_QTY VARCHAR(255),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(255),
    PACKAGE_TYPE VARCHAR(255),
    NUMBER_OF_DIE_IN_PKG VARCHAR(255), 
    LEAD_COUNT VARCHAR(255), 
    PACKAGE_SIZE VARCHAR(255),
    CONFIGURATION_WIDTH VARCHAR(255),
    RPM_WW VARCHAR(255),
    TC_WEIGHT VARCHAR(255),
    QA_BURN_EXPERIMENT VARCHAR(255),
    QA_CONTACT_NAME VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO table_a
    select 
        LOT_LOCATION, 
        LOTID, 
        DESIGN_ID,
        QA_WORK_REQUEST_NO,
        COALESCE(B.priority, A.PRIORITY, 4) AS PRIORITY,
        QA_PROCESS_TYPE, 
        QA_PROCESS_NAME, 
        LOCATION_DATE AS START_TIME,
        ENV_TEST_INTERVAL,
        ROUND(EST_DURATION_TIME),
        ROUND(EST_DURATION_TIME /24) AS days,
        HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), LOCATION_DATE)) AS elapsed,
        BINOUT_DUE_DATE AS END_TIME,
        CURRENT_QTY,
        A.LOCATION,
        PACKAGE_TYPE,
        NUMBER_OF_DIE_IN_PKG, 
        LEAD_COUNT, 
        CONCAT(trim(PACKAGE_WIDTH)+0,'x',trim(PACKAGE_LENGTH)+0,'x',trim(PACKAGE_HEIGHT)+0) AS PACKAGE_SIZE,
        CONFIGURATION_WIDTH,
        RPM_WW,
        TC_WEIGHT,
        QA_BURN_EXPERIMENT,
        QA_CONTACT
    from
        skynet_msa.labs_inventory A LEFT JOIN skynet_msa.lab_inv_prio B ON A.LOTID = B.lot_id 
    where 
        (lot_location like 'SGHAST%' or lot_location like 'SGTHS%' or lot_location like 'SGBAKE%' or lot_location like 'SGTC%' or lot_location like 'SGTHB%' or lot_location like 'SGTS%' or lot_location like 'SGREFLOW%') 
    and
        module_lot != 1   
    order by 
        lot_location;

ALTER TABLE table_a
ADD COLUMN `row_created` Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ADD COLUMN `Zone Attribute` VARCHAR(255) AFTER LOT_LOCATION;
```

So whenever I run the query on task scheduler, the query will fail and only gives me the result of the table as only headers with no values in all the columns, however, most of the time when I run manually it works well.

This is because sometimes the code will take too long to insert to the table and they will say:

```
Error Code 2013: Lost Connection to MySQL during query
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check your command execution timeout parameter on the server. Supervise your job with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or other monitoring tools.

Comment: @tadman the insert portion sometimes can take 0.016-29 seconds or above 30 seconds. Do u know how to make it to always be around 0.016 second?

Comment: This is a question for a DBA that can have a closer look at your schema, your server, your network, and more, to make informed recommendations.

Comment: @tadman I notice that queries that insert into the table the data from pre-existing tables tend to run the longest. Do u have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Not having any idea of the parameters I just mentioned, no, I do not know a magical solution. This requires a lot of careful troubleshooting, but start with the obvious: Has your server ever been tuned? Is it under a lot of load?

Comment: how to check for them?

Comment: @tadman it has not been tuned and idk how to know whether it's under a lot of load

Comment: *I run the query on task scheduler* Do not use external task scheduler, use built-in Event Scheduler instead. Also use one CREATE TABLE .. SELECT instead of 3 separate queries.

Comment: thank u will take that into account!

Comment: The default tuning for MySQL is **atrocious**. If you're using InnoDB, which I really hope you are, give [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) as  much memory as you can afford to spare. The performance difference can be multiple *orders of magnitude*.

Comment: making shorter queries work however i am currently working on a query that still fails me perhaps u can help me and check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73044738/how-to-make-my-mysql-query-more-efficient-since-the-query-keeps-failing-wheneve